# GPO is applied but not showing

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, system-administration

i want every user in my domain to have a specific link in their desktop.
what i did to achieve it:
created a GPO and linked it to a OU, the GPO was edited like that:
user configuration --> preferences --> windows settings --> shortcuts --> new shortcut (the configuration of the shortcut is in the images)

[General](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XJDN.png)

[Common](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSKUf.png)

inside the item-level targeting i added a security group.

that security group is in the OU that the GPO is linked to and there is a user that he is inside that security group and he is also inside of the OU that the gpo is linked to.

in summary:

user --> security group --> OU

GPO --> OU

At the end i run "gpupdate" on the users computer (the user is logged on to the computer) and the link isn't showing in the desktop but when i run "gpresult /r" i see that the gpo is applied.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong but looking at your picture you are setting up the shortcut wrong.

You are using the replace action, this is wrong it should be update.

The rest looks ok, the GPO will run but as it is incorrect it will never create it.

I have set up shortcuts before and this was how i did it.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2014/02/17/adding-shortcuts-on-desktop-using-group-policy-preferences-in-windows-8-and-windows-8-1/

Comment: I tried the link you provided and its not working for me,
its important to say that it did work at first but then i added the item level targeting and it gave me the same problem as before.
it says that the GPO is applied and nothing is showing

Comment: Can i ask why you are using item level targeting? I have never used it before and have never needed to use it either

Comment: I solved it by doing a restart at the desired computer.
i want to do it so that the link will appear only on my boss desktop so he could see how it looks like and approve to add it to the rest of the company.

Comment: Gpupdate /force has the same effect, sorry i didnt notice that you hadnt used force